How to use dependency injection with latest AutoCAD API 2025 where .NET 8 was introduced?
New AutoCAD 2025 comes with .NET 8 which is basically .NET Core so I am assuming dependency injection should be a no brainer for autocad addins as well, but..
I haven't found a single word about it on whole internet, yet it should be a very basic way how to handle dependencies if they are going with .NET 8. Is there at least tiny example how to register services, configure some options and build service container for AutoCAD addon and consume it somewhere else like command method? Autodesk blogs are silent about this. I need to use my previously written services that I use for ASP.NET core WEB API projects for working with Forge APIs inside AutoCAD design automation plugin.
I have tried to use HostBuilder and register a single foo service but it won't even load the plugin, no error.

Dependency Injection is when you inject any dependency. Period. It is not bound to any framework or special language. So your assumption does not make sense in any way

Please show me that native support in .net core - I am very interested. I know the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection nuget packages but that is not native support and was built around IServiceProvider which is known from .Net Framework v1.0. Here is an explanation what Dependency Injection is.


so I am assuming dependency injection should be a no brainer for autocad addins as well

It is hard to know what you mean. It is definitely possible to use code like this in an addin:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
sp.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

What are you looking for exactly?

That is indeed what I am looking for but I am also looking for some kind of host builder where I could place everything to startup class to be able to call UseXXX methods (Serilog) etc. This way I assume I will place serviceprovider as static variable on application class and get services through it every time.

Well, then write an extension method that does it

I don't understand the connection to HostBuilder. You can use DI independent of HostBuilder. What forces you go the HostBuilder route?

Nothing really, I was actually trying without it, but I did not succeeded yet, because I could not use hostbuilder.userserilog way of registering it, that is all. Similar way I need to add appsettings.json configuration
to able to run shared services that uses microsoft ILogger and IConfiguration in web api projects.
